# XML File location in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Where is situated xml file, that consist of name of module and name of view in Magento 1.9? This file is downloaded one of the first and loads all the pages. Sorry for stupid question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are diffrent XML avilable into the extension like this.

```
 1. Magento Root->app->etc->modules->Extension.xml

 2. Magento Root->add->code->CODEPOOL->Vendor->Extension->etc->config.xml
```

Mainly all information related extension store in these files.

Comment: No, you told about the configs of a particular module, and I need a project. Which load the module and module view. With the help of this in the view, you can write $this and access the fields of this module.

Comment: Look the question you are asking about the extension name and other inforamtion are avilable in config.xml, I post answer with location as well which help you.

Comment: Sorry, I agree, that my question was unarticulated. May be u know where is config.xml situated?

Comment: For the extension config.xml path are already given to you in my above answer.